# How do I trigger an event whenever an HTML page gets longer?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a page with an iframe.  The iframe contents sometimes do dynamic JS things that cause them to grow.  When thta happens, I have to resize the iframe to make sure it's long enough, which I do with this, inside the iframe:

```
// I saved you the boredom of all the try{}s and != nulls, this is just the meat.
document.parentWindow.parent.reSize();
```

And this, which is in the parent html:

```
function reSize()
{
    try
    {
        var oBody   =   ifrm.document.body;
        var oFrame  =   document.all('ifrm');

        oFrame.style.height = oBody.scrollHeight + (oBody.offsetHeight - oBody.clientHeight) + 100;
    }
    //An error is raised if the IFrame domain != its container's domain
    catch(e) { }
}
```

However, calls to this are littered all over, in every place where resizing might have happened.  Is there anywhere I can put this such that it is "automatic"?  Some event I can trigger off of or something?

Relevant links:

- [How do I detect iframe resize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286887/how-to-detect-iframe-iframe-resize)
- [resize iframe dynamically in ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495130/resize-iframe-dynamically-in-asp)
- [how to detect iframe resize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088426/how-to-detect-iframe-resize)

Comment: Are you using jQuery/would you like vanilla JS-only solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems to be working, on Firefox, Chrome 16, and IE 8, at least.  It is derived from @TimWickstrom.com's answer, but with the outer-frame stuff removed and some modifications to height calculations:

```
<iframe id='ifrm' width='100%' scrolling='no' ...>

var iFrame = document.getElementById('ifrm'); 
function stateChange(){ if (obj.readyState=='loading') { scroll(0,0); } }
iFrame.onreadystatechange='stateChange()';
var iFrameHeight = -1;
function resizeIframe() {
    var iFrameBody = typeof iFrame.contentDocument != 'undefined' ? iFrame.contentDocument.body : iFrame.contentWindow.document.body;
    if (iFrameBody == null) return;
    var newiFrameHeight = typeof window.innerHeight != 'undefined' ? iFrameBody.scrollHeight : (iFrameBody.scrollHeight + iFrameBody.offsetHeight - iFrameBody.clientHeight);
    if(iFrameHeight != newiFrameHeight) {
        iFrameHeight = newiFrameHeight;
        iFrame.style.height = newiFrameHeight;
    }
}
iFrame.onload = function() { setInterval('resizeIframe()', 100); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Place this code right above the closing body tag of the parent window. place your iframe resizing code where commented.

OLD CODE:

```
<script>
    var intWinHeight = (typeof window.innerHeight != 'undefined' ? window.innerHeight : document.body.offsetHeight);

    var resizeIframe = function() {
        var newWinHeight = (typeof window.innerHeight != 'undefined' ? window.innerHeight : document.body.offsetHeight);
        if(newWinHeight != intWinHeight) {
            intWinHeight = newWinHeight;
            // execute your Iframe resizing code here

        }
    }
    setInterval(resizeIframe, 100);
</script>
```

NEW CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var iFrameId = document.getElementById('myIframe');
    var intWinHeight = (typeof window.innerHeight != 'undefined' ? window.innerHeight : document.body.offsetHeight);
    var intIframHeight = (typeof iFrameId.contentWindow.window.innerHeight != 'undefined' ? iFrameId.contentWindow.window.innerHeight : iFrameId.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight);
    function exeResizeIframe() {
        var newWinHeight = (typeof window.innerHeight != 'undefined' ? window.innerHeight : document.body.offsetHeight);
        var newIframHeight = (typeof iFrameId.contentWindow.window.innerHeight != 'undefined' ? iFrameId.contentWindow.window.innerHeight : iFrameId.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight);
        if((newWinHeight != intWinHeight) || intIframHeight != newIframHeight) {
            intWinHeight = newWinHeight;
            intIframHeight = newIframHeight;
            // execute your Iframe resizing code here

        }
    }
    setInterval("exeResizeIframe()", 100);
</script>
```

Please note, change the iframe ID
due to security restrictions in IE < 9 only local paths will work in the ifram src

Comment: If I understand right, this code will only trigger the "Iframe resizing code" when the browser window itself resizes, yes?  I need to to trigger when the contents of the iframe dynamically resizes itself, not (only) when the browser changes size.

Comment: +1 because I got quite a bit of use out of this - thanks - but polished it a little more and posted that in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a custom event after doing the "dynamic JS things." Elsewhere, attach just a single listener whose callback executes the `document.parentWindow.parent.reSize();`.

Further reading:

- [Custom event in HTML, Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927419/custom-event-in-html-javascript)
- [How to trigger event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe bind an event in parent window that resizes the iframe and trigger it whenever the dynamic js causes it to grow (trigger it from the iframe content.
look at this post:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/trigger-from-iframe-to-parent-window